# Did Robert Picardo have a cold in 'Jetrel'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-emh

This may seem a bit of a weird question (to be honest, it is) but I was watching the Voyager episode 'Jetrel' and noticed that whenever the EMH spoke, he sounded like he was suffering from a cold.  I also noted he didn't feature much in this episode, which struck me as odd considering the significant biological aspects of this episode.  **Did Robert Picardo have a cold during the filming of this episode?**

Comment: Given the EMH is a computer program, maybe he had a virus...? :D

Comment: I always thought that John Anderson (the Douwd in "The Survivors") had a cold during the filming of the episode. It's certainly possible that Picardo did as well.

Comment: How many people read this as "Did **Picard** have a cold in 'Jetrel'"?

Comment: @N_Soong I admit it took me two reads to get it right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Possible, but no confirmation

[image]

It is certainly possible that Robert Picardo was under the weather during filming of "Jetrel", but there is no explicit confirmation of it.  I've gone through as many Robert Picardo interviews as I can, and he has not made reference to that episode.  No one on the staff has mentioned that he was ill during filming of that episode.

Regarding the Doctor's screen time in the episode, it's worth nothing that the focus in the episode was intended to be squarely on Neelix and Jetrel, as [these quotes](http://voy.trekcore.com/episodes/season1/1x15/behindscenes.html) from the creative staff suggest.

Comment: This kind of thing has plenty of precedents. The actor who played Les Nesman in *WKRP in Cincinnati* had a minor injury when they taped the first episode, and the writers turned it into a running gag where Les was constantly wearing bandages.